# Reduce to first order and solve $yy'' = 3y'^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Reduce to first order and solve $yy'' = 3y'^2$

Dividing both sides by $y$ and re-arranging  $y'' - 3y' = 0$. This is clearly an homogenous equation, a solution might be $e^{3x}$to test this:
$y' = 3e^{3x}, y'' = 9e^{3x} \implies 9e^x-9e^x = 0$

Substituting $y = ue^{3x}, y' = u'e^{3x}+3ue^{3x}, y'' = u''e^{3x}+3u'e^{3x}+3u'e^{3x}+9ue^{3x}$

Plugging these in $$(u''e^{3x}+3u'e^{3x}+3u'e^{3x}+9ue^{3x})-3\cdot (u'e^{3x}+3ue^{3x})=0$$
$$\implies u''e^{3x}+3u'e^{3x}=0$$

Substituting $v = u'$

$$\implies v'e^{3x}+3ve^{3x}=0$$
$$=\int\frac{dv}{v} = 3\int dx$$

However the solution to this exercise is $(c_1x+c_2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ , how did they get this?

Comment: divide both sides by $y$ gives you $y'' = \frac{3y'^2}{y}$, not what you have. You should divide both sides by $yy'$ instead.

Comment: @achillehui Ah okay, I'll give this one a go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algebra is wrong, it would be $y'' - 3{(y')^2 \over y} = 0$.

It's better to write it as ${y'' \over y'} = 3{y' \over y}$ and view ${y'' \over y'}$ as the derivative of $\ln |y'|$, and similarly ${y' \over y}$ as the derivative of $\ln |y|$. Then you can reduce the order by integrating both sides.

Comment: I've integrated both sides and got this $ln(y') = 3ln(yc) \implies y' = \frac{y'}{y} = 3c \implies ln(y) = 3xc + d$ and if I continue I don't get the solution as above

Comment: It will be $\ln(y') = 3\ln(y) + C$, which exponentiates to $y' = Dy^3$ (for a different constant $D$. See if you can take it from there.

Comment: Ah I see! Perhaps the solution by the book is wrong, as I get this (unless my method is wrong): $\int \frac{dy}{y^3} = D \int dx \implies -\frac{1}{2y^2} = Dx + c \implies y = (-2xc_1 - c_2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: Since it's $y^2$ it becomes $\pm (-2xc_1 - c_2)^{-{1 \over 2}}$. But you can just change constant names to replace $-2c_1$ by $c_1$ and $-c_2$ by $c_2$ to get $\pm (c_1 x + c_2)^{-{1 \over 2}}$, which is almost their solution.

Comment: Also, there is the zero solution which we missed here because of the $y$ in the denominator in our arguments.

Answer (score 1):

How do you cancel $y$? Observe instead that the equation can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{yy''-(y')^2}{(y')^2}=2
$$
and that the left-hand side is the derivative of $-y/y'$.

Now $y=(c_1-2x)y'$ which is separable and becomes
$$
\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{1}{c_1-2x}
$$
hence, after integrating and removing the logarithms,
$$
y=c_2(c_1-2x)^{-1/2}
$$
You might also write it as
$$
y=c_2(c_1-x)^{-1/2}
$$
but I dare say that the book's solution is incomplete (it doesn't provide solutions with $y<0$) if not incorrect.

Comment: This is an interesting approach, though I have a question. If the LHS is the derivative then it should look like this $\frac{dy}{dx}(-y/y') = 2 \implies yy' dy = -2x+c$ what happens to $dy$ in this instance?

Comment: It should be $d(-y/y')/dx$ or, to be safe, set $z=-y/y'$ and so you have $dz/dx=2$. That's the danger of Leibniz notation. Actually you just integrate both sides to get $-y/y'+c=2x$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint...you can't cancel $y$ like you have. Instead put $y''=y'\frac{dy'}{dy}$ and the result will follow.

Comment: Where did the $3$ go?

Comment: substitute this alternative expression for $y''$ into your de

Comment: This example is new to me but I have tried: $y \left(y' \frac{dy}{dx} \right) = 3y' \implies \frac{ydy}{dx}=3 \implies \int ydy = 3\int x dx$ however this does not give me the answer above

Comment: you have misread what I have written